# ¿Cómo resolver el error de "esp_timer.h" en el nodemcu esp8266?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

estoy queriendo hacer un ejemplo del sensor Sensirion SCD30 en el Node MCU esp8266, cargo las librerías faltantes pero al compilar, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Arduino:1.8.19 (Windows Store 1.8.57.0) (Windows 10), Tarjeta:"NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

sketch_jul16a:2:10: fatal error: esp_timer.h: No such file or directory

    2 | #include <esp_timer.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.
Se encontraron varias bibliotecas para "Adafruit_Sensor.h"
Usado: C:\Users\Ely\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Sensor-master
 No usado: C:\Users\Ely\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Unified_Sensor
exit status 1
esp_timer.h: No such file or directory
```

He copiado el código de varios githubs pero no corre y los coloco en los ejercicios que quiero hacer y nada. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Hola! Te corresponde [edit] y compartir lo que genera este error a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que puedas recibir respuesta rápidamente. Difícilmente sabemos cuáles son los githubs que has usado ni el ejemplo que estás probando. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes configurado *Tools -> Board*?